NextJS Transformers Module parse failed: Unexpected character
I need to create embeddings in NextJS 15, so I started looking into @xenova/transformers and @huggingface/transformers. It was too simple to implement in a Node script (without NextJS), but I am struggling to make this work.
After the project creation, I created an API route as usual (/app/api/route.ts) and proceeded with the given example:
import { pipeline } from '@huggingface/transformers'

export async function GET() {
    const extractor = await pipeline(
        'feature-extraction',
        'Xenova/all-MiniLM-L6-v2'
    )

    const sentences = ['This is an example sentence', 'Each sentence is converted'];
    const output = await extractor(sentences, { pooling: 'mean', normalize: true });

    console.log(output)
}

But when I visit the API URL I get this error:

./node_modules/@huggingface/transformers/node_modules/onnxruntime-node/bin/napi-v3/darwin/arm64/onnxruntime_binding.node
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)

I have tried also to update the Next configuration file next.config.ts with:
import type { NextConfig } from "next";

const nextConfig: NextConfig = {
  output: 'standalone',
  serverExternalPackages: ['sharp', 'onnxruntime-node'] 
};

export default nextConfig;

I don't really know how to proceed and implement this in the server side (API routes). If I need a loader, I don't know how to implement it.

Looks like file's encoding is changed, change encoding to utf-8 in vs code and then try.
